# Istio egress traffic is not routed through istio istio-proxy sidecar

Tags: kubernetes, istio

we have a minimal example of routing egress traffic to an external service outside of the service mesh.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: nexus-test
  namespace: REDACTED
spec:
  hosts:
  - nexus.REDACTED
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: https
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
```

But we are not seeing the traffic pass the sidecar istio-proxy using the command

`kubectl logs $SOURCE_POD -c istio-proxy | tail`

Also we are not seeing the traffic on the mixer using the command:

`kubectl -n istio-system logs -l istio-mixer-type=telemetry -c mixer | grep 'nexus'`

as suggested in the documentation https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/#access-an-external-https-service

Can anyone help us what could be wrong?

Best regards,
rforberger

Comment: I see in the egress gateway logs the following:
`[debug][init] [external/envoy/source/common/init/manager_impl.cc:45] init manager Cluster outbound|443||nexus.REDACTED contains no targets`
And in the pilot:
`RejectedTCP=nexus.REDACTED`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now. It was maybe conflicting with other services in the service mesh.